# Created files and can see them with DDMS but they do not appear within Windows file Explorer

Tags: android

I'm creating several .xml files for export.

Using

```
Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
```

I can export them successfully to the appropriate path I want to.

I can then see the files using DDMS.  I can not however see the files on my device using the file explorer.  Yes, I turned off debugging and can see all other files and folders.

Answer (score 2):

You do not indicate what device you are seeing this on. If it is running Android 3.0 or higher, then you will need to scan the file. Quoting myself from a [blog post](http://commonsware.com/blog/2011/08/31/mtp-external-storage.html):

> However, there is a more subtle shift that is important to developers: the MTP contents are not based on the literal contents of external storage. Instead, MTP contents are based on what files have been scanned by `MediaScannerConnection`. If you write a file to external storage, until and unless that file is scanned by `MediaScannerConnection`, it will not be visible to users over MTP.
>
> External storage is scanned on a reboot and possibly on a periodic basis. Users can manually force a scan via utilities like SDRescan. However, the best answer is for you to use `scanFile()` on `MediaScannerConnection` to update the media database after you close your file. This will make your file immediately available to the user.